# regular sequence and flatness

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

Suppose $R$ is a Noetherian local ring and $a,b$ is a regular sequence in $R$. Now let $T$ be an indeterminate and $B=\frac{R[T]}{(aT-b)}$.

Is $B$ a flat $R$ module? If not, under what conditions (say if it is reduced?) is it flat?

Comment: I can see that to show $B$ is a flat $R$ module, we have to show $Tor_1(B/R/I)=0$ for every $R$-ideal $I$. So we have to show that the map $(aT-b)\otimes R/I\rightarrow R/I[T]$ is injective. But it looks like it is true.

Comment: From Bourbaki: If $0\to K\to L\to M\to 0$ is a ses of $R$-modules, $L$ is free, $M$ is flat, and $K\subseteq J(R)L$ ($J(R)$ stands for the Jacobson radical), then $K=0$. Set $L=R[T]$, $M=B$ and $K=(aT-b)$. Then it's impossible to have $K=(0)$, so your $B$ is never $R$-flat.

Comment: Thanks! got it. I was wondering if the modules L,M are finitely generated over R? or does it work for every module?

Comment: This is exercise 23(d), chapter I, section 2, from Bourbaki CA, and doesn't require extra-conditions. (Please check it.)

Comment: I think tensoring $0\to R[T] \to R[T] \to R[T]/(aT-b) \to 0$ with $R/(a,b)$ works to show $Tor_1(R/(a,b),B) \ne 0$.

Comment: I like @JakeLevinson's idea. Similarly, one can use the fact that $b,a$ form a regular sequence on $B$ if $B$ were flat. However, $aT$ is zero in $B/bB \cong R[T]/(aT,b)$.